# Begin stream a movie from DLNA Media Server to a DLNA Media Renderer

Tags: upnp, dlna

I want to stream a movie from a DLNA Media Server to a DLNA Media Renderer (a TV in this case). However, I want to be able to initiate it from a DLNA Media Controller, regardless of what state the TV is in (as long as it's on, connected and in normal usage).

Thus, is there any action that can be send from the DMC to force the DMR to start stream content from the DMS?

I'm looking for an action that can be used on any DLNA Media Renderer certified TV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881690.aspx

check this

http://teleal.org/projects/cling/support/manual/cling-support-manual.html

You should use ContentDirectory service to get data from media server and use AVttransport to play the data on medirenderer.